# Output Name in PHP From mysql Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have a list of names in a database that i want to display one by one

(also for bonus points, another column in the database is a Boolean value for if a task is completed or not.  if this is true i want the css content box background to be green instead of red.)

so how can i select a name from row one, put it to a PHP variable, then select the value from the "Name" column in row 2 and put that to another PHP variable or the next item in the array?

thanks for any help!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mngPWinCSS.css"/>


</head>

<body>
    <?php

        $dsn ='mysql:host=****.******.com;dbname=o****_**n';
        $username='********';
        $password ='******';

        mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM CLOAS_Team LIMIT 0,1");
        $bob="dkajfk";


        $url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header("Refresh: 60; URL=$url"); 
        $com[1]="i";
        $com[2]="i";
        $com[3]="i";
        $com[4]="i";
        $com[5]="i";
        $com[6]="i";
        $name=mysql_fetch_array($query);



    ?>
    <div id="content">
        <img src="logjpg.JPG" alt="Smiley face" height="50" width="200">
    <h3>CLOAS Tracker</h3>

    </div>
     <div id="Content">
        <?php

        ?>

        <div id="complete">
            <h3names>
                <?php 
                    echo $name['Name'];
                ?>
            </h3names>
        </div>
        <div id="incomplete">
            <h3names>Name2</h3names>
        </div>

     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be deprecated in PHP 5.5. It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: What is with the `$bob` and `$com` variables?  Why do you have a refresh header?  What is a `h3names` tag?

Comment: $bob was used as test variable and the $com are test right now, but hope to implement them later...not really relevant now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to change your SELECT query to select all of the rows that you wish to display, perhaps by taking off the LIMIT clause. Something like this;

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM CLOAS_Team");
```

(This will get you all of the names in your table.)

Next, you need to loop through the results you got from this query, like so;

```
$names = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$names[] = $row['Name'];
}
```

This will put them into the array $names for you, which you can then work with. Instead of putting them into the array, you might want to output them immediately, perhaps like this;

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ ?>
<div>
            <h3>
                <?php 
                    echo $row['Name'];
                ?>
            </h3>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

However, you have many more errors in your code. Such as;

- You can't just invent html elements called `<h3names>`
- I doubt that you want to set the id attribute to 'incomplete'. An id should be unique, I expect you should be putting this in as a class (class = "incomplete")
- I don't think your line `header("Refresh: 60; URL=$url");` will do anything as your headers have already been sent to the page. If you want this line to work, it needs to be right at the top, BEFORE any output has been sent to the browser.

And for the bonus point, include the 'Completed' field in your query (if that is what it is called) and use this to add a style to each `<div>` element that you display in your loop. So your query might become;

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT Name, Completed FROM CLOAS_Team");
```

And your loop would now be like this;

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { ?>
    <div style = "background-color:<?php echo $row['Completed'] == true ? 'green' : ' red'; ?>">
                <h3>
                    <?php 
                        echo $row['Name'];
                    ?>
                </h3>
            </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I was having issues and I still didnt get an output.  I put in your first suggestion (
$names = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$names[] = $row['Name'];
}
)
Then i placed an echo count($names) where i had just the echo $names.  The count is 0.  Is there a way to check my connection and database credentials easily or do you think there is a different issue?

Comment: so I found the issue...it was in my hostname. Thank you for all your help though! I'm definitely learning a lot.